# How do I use Chef data bags from my Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, json, chef-infra, vagrant

I am attempting to use [Fnichol's Chef User](http://fnichol.github.io/chef-user/) recipe with Vagrant to automatically create a specific user account when I run `vagrant up`. Because I setup this user for nearly every project that I work on, I'd like to store the user data in a `data bag` that I am loading from a JSON file that I can re-use on multiple projects.

This is what my `Vagrantfile` currently looks like: http://pastebin.com/b0riZZCz

It fails with the error:

```
[2014-01-20T16:09:39+00:00] ERROR: could not find recipe ben for cookbook user
```

I have created a `data bag` called "users" and inside that data bag I've created a `data bag item` named "ben" from the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": "ben",
  "comment": "Ben Harold",
  "groups": ["admin", "www-data"],
  "ssh_keys": ["...longtextstring..."],
  "ssh_keygen": false
}
```

I'm attempting to follow the usage instructions at http://fnichol.github.io/chef-user/ to:

1. Import the Chef Users recipe
2. Tell the Chef Users recipe to create the user `ben` from the data bag `users`

It appears to me that the Chef provisioning syntax from within a `Vagrantfile` is considerably different than the syntax that is presented in most of the available documentation. For example:

> "Simply include `recipe[user]` in your `run_list` and the `user_account`
>   resource will be available."

I'm confused as to the definition of `run_list`, as well as the `recipe[user]` syntax. From the [Vagrant documentation](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html), it seems that my `run_list` is everything in this block:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.add_recipe "apt"
  ...etc...
end
```

However, I've [also found references](http://www.iflowfor8hours.info/2013/11/vagrant-and-databags-learning-experience/) to `chef.run_list` being defined within that block, although I have not been able to find any documentation specifically referring to `chef.run_list`.

### Question 1

Is the `run_list` simply the code within the `config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|` block, or is it something else?

### Question 2

Where is the documentation for `chef.run_list`? I'm not looking for the documentation on the Chef site. The syntax seems completely different to me.

I've been messing with this for several hours. I've tried a bunch of stuff that does not work. I am able to import the `Chef User` recipe, but I haven't been able to figure out how to tell Chef to run the `user` recipe against the `data bag item` "ben".

### Question 3

How do I get Chef to run the `user` recipe with the `data bag item` "ben"? Or am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 4):

**Answer 1**

No, `run_list` is actually just an array of strings, that represent recipes/roles that should be run on Vagrant Machine. And add_recipe adds new recipes into this list. Like that:

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  [...]
  chef.add_recipe 'cookbook::recipe' #now run_list has it in
  chef.add_role 'myrole' #now run_list has a role too
  #adding more recipes from ENV variable, just as example
  chef.run_list += ENV['CHEF_RUN_LIST'].split ',' if ENV.has_key? 'CHEF_RUN_LIST' 
  [...]
end
```

**Answer 2**

You are editing Vagrantfile, so documentation is on [Vagrant site](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/chef_solo.html)

**Answer 3**

You need to tell Vagrant where are your cookbooks, data bags and roles.

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  [...]
  chef.cookbooks_path = 'cookbooks' #paths are relative to Vagrantfile location
  chef.roles_path = 'roles'
  chef.data_bags_path = 'data_bags'
  [...]
end
```

Comment: How do I convert the syntax `recipe[user::data_bag]` seen at http://fnichol.github.io/chef-user/ to the syntax in a Vagrantfile?

Comment: Add a role and recipe using above mentioned `add_role` and `add_recipe` and print run_list with `p chef.run_list` - you will see how they are saved. In your case `chef.add_recipe 'user::data_bag'`